# What is the best spell checking library for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, spell-checking

What's the best spell checking library for C# / .net?

(This will be web-based, so the built in spell check for WPF won't work.)

Answer (score 37):

I've made a .NET version (wrapper) of the Open Office / Google Chrome ... spell checker Hunspell. It is called [NHunspell](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/) and can be used with C#/ VB / .... The Open Office hyphenator "Hyphen" is also included. All Open Office dictionaries work. It is free (open source LGPL / MPL licensed).

Comment: I've used this library in a recent project and it works well. Biggest issue seems to be the Open Office dictionaries are not very good. Lots of word misses and bad matches it seems.

Answer (score 6):

I have used **[Aspell.net](http://aspell-net.sourceforge.net/)** before with some success.

Comment: GPL for spell checking?

Answer (score 3):

I have used NetSpell in the past with success. http://sourceforge.net/projects/netspell/

Comment: Just tried this one, it seems to work pretty well for very basic usage.

Comment: Jason Jackson or @blue_fenix, can you please show a snippet or point out what I'm missing in NetSpell? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751263/netspell-spellchecker

Answer (score 1):

There is a aspell .net wrapper.

http://aspell-net.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

For a custom solution I created a Web Service which then wrapped the WPF libraries. This gives the ability to use the built-in spell checking with ASP.NET applications/web sites by simply calling the Web Service.

An easy to follow and basic idea for the wrapping can be found here:

http://www.quicklearn.com/blogsamples/SpellCheck.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For a commercial solution:

I am currently evaluating RapidSpell and it seems be what I need.  I will say that their demo install *seemed* to trash my third-party installs.  (*Something* did, and I noticed it right after installing their demo.  But that may have been coincidence.)

Comment: For another try ASPNetSpell - http://www.aspnetspell.com

Answer (score 0):

Telerik's control suite for ASP.NET comes with a spell-checker. You might check them out.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/Spell/Examples/Overview/DefaultCS.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You could embed the WPF spell checker using silverlight. Otherwise you might want to look at commercial products that are already available such as [Telerik's ASP.NET AJAX Controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx).