# How to add spell check in a richtextbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, spell-checking

I want to add spell check to my richtextboxes in my application. How can i do that with built in classes in visual studio express 2010?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453611/what-is-the-best-spell-checking-library-for-c

Comment: i tried to use System.Windows.Controls SpellCheck Class but i don''t know what are the references i should add to get it working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to use the C# SpellCheck class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024798/trying-to-use-the-c-sharp-spellcheck-class)

Comment: It is WinForms application. Yes

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at this?  `System.Windows.Controls.SpellCheck`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.aspx

Comment: I did but when i tried to insert "using System.Windows.Controls;" it doesn't get recognized in my code

Comment: that because you need to reference the PresentationFramework.dll

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on WPF,  you can use System.Windows.Controls.SpellCheck.

but if you using WinForms you can still use WPF spellcheck with some work.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024798/trying-to-use-the-c-sharp-spellcheck-class) SO question for more info.

Otherwise you need to use third party [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453611/what-is-the-best-spell-checking-library-for-c).

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Third Party Control (Infragistics) **UltraSpellChecker**. Its really easy to work with it.

```
this.ultraSpellChecker1.SetSpellCheckerSettings(this.txt_comment, new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinSpellChecker.SpellCheckerSettings(true));
```

where `txt_comment` is the richtextbox in which you want your spellings to be checked.