# NetSpell spellchecker

Tags: c#, spell-checking

Has anyone tried [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5277/NetSpell-Spell-Checker-for-NET) out? I cannot get it to work. For example, the spelling suggestions should work as follows.

But I am getting an empty list back. 
I first got an exception saying

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft
>   shared\DevServer\10.0\en-us.dic

is missing so I downloaded it from the web. The file I got has a list of thousands of english words and I even tried words from what it in the file and still no luck.

He is some code I tried.

```
Spelling s = new Spelling();
ArrayList items;
s.MaxSuggestions = 5;
s.SuggestionMode = Spelling.SuggestionEnum.PhoneticNearMiss;
s.Suggest(str);
items = s.Suggestions;
s.SuggestionMode = Spelling.SuggestionEnum.NearMiss;
s.Suggest(str);
items = s.Suggestions;
s.SuggestionMode = Spelling.SuggestionEnum.Phonetic;
s.Suggest(str);
items = s.Suggestions;
```

The Suggest method is supposed to get suggestions for 'str' and populate the Suggestions property. I am always getting 0 suggestions. I tried all three suggestion types that the library supports to see if that does anything as you can see, but that does not work either.

Even simple calls such as

```
s.TestWord("book")
```

give back "false". I think it is not able to use the dictionary file but not sure what else to do about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is what it was, the dic file was not compatible. I just used the one that comes with when you download NetSpell and it works like a charm.

By the way, I switche to NHunspell and I like it much better than NetSpell. Easier to use and better suggestions.
http://www.crawler-lib.net/nhunspell