# Validate if the word a is almost same as the word b

Tags: c#, regex

If you have the string a = "Super rich rush to buy superyachts" and you have the string b = "ruush to buyy".

My question is:
Is it possible to use regex to make a confirmation if almost all word from the string "a"  is the same from the string "b"? If yes, how?

Comment: "almost" is subjective - regex isn't very good at being subjective. You're likely looking for something like the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the strings being below some threshold, rather than a regular expression.

Comment: No, that's not really what regex is for.

Comment: I think you're going to have to use a spell-checking library.  Examples here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453611/what-is-the-best-spell-checking-library-for-c

Comment: see if you can write out a precise definition of 'almost the same'. If you can then write the code that does that

Comment: Might be worth reading up on the Edit Distance algorithm.

Comment: If you need strictly regex answer - NO. For more practical answer see linked duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453731/how-to-calculate-distance-similarity-measure-of-given-2-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about using only regexes, but one algorithm often used for this sort of "fuzzy matching" is [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

There are many existing C# implementations out there. One nice one is Google's [Diff-match-patch](https://github.com/lqc/google-diff-match-patch)