# Couldn't find info about creating spellcheck for words with our library in C#

Tags: c#, spelling

I couldn't find any info , about creating a spell checker which reads a word from .txt file.

I will be glad if you can help with anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best spell checking library for C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453611/what-is-the-best-spell-checking-library-for-c)

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you can use the [NHunspell](http://www.crawler-lib.net/nhunspell) library.

Your check method in this case is very simple and looks like this:

```
 bool CheckSpell(string word)
    {         
        using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_GB.aff", "en_GB.dic"))
        {
            return hunspell.Spell(word);               
        }
    }
```

You can find dictionaries on [this site](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries).

Also you can use [SpellCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.aspx) class:

```
bool CheckSpell(string word)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Text = word;
    tb.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;

    int index = tb.GetNextSpellingErrorCharacterIndex(0, LogicalDirection.Forward);
    if (index == -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: thnx for info, but i want to create my own library

Comment: it is simple to create library dll if you implement this code example.

Comment: **[How to Write a Spelling Corrector in C#](http://www.anotherchris.net/csharp/how-to-write-a-spelling-corrector-in-csharp/)** This link is the 3rd solution for spell checker and correcter.